# Where Can I get a Web Server or File Share Server?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to publish my program so that it can get updates and am told I have to publish my changes to a web server or file share server, but I have no idea about how I can go about getting one...are there free ones that will perform what I need to accomplish?

---

Ok, I don't know what to do and comments seem to go ignored.

I've tried setting the publish location to sites.google.com/site/mysite.com/filecabinetpage/PQCMFILES

and I got an error saying I needed "Front Page Server Extension Capabilities".

I tried setting it to http://productivityquotient.hostzi.com/PQCMFILES/ and it told me:
Error   1   Failed to connect to 'http://productivityquotient.hostzi.com/PQCMFILES/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'http://productivityquotient.hostzi.com/PQCMFILES'.  An error occurred accessing your site configuration files. Authors - if authoring against a web server, please contact the webmaster for this server's site.  Webmasters - please see the server's application event log for more details.        1   1   Contact Manager

I tried setting it to a directory on the microsoft site and it said: "unable to create directory. files moved" or something like that.

I can't host it on an ftp server if I intend to use the updates feature and I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Microsoft's free web hosting](http://smallbusiness.officelive.com/en-us/) will allow you to do this.

Comment: I like this idea up of what has been presented if: I can set my publish location on a site here. I'm not sure how. Anyone know how for any of the suggestions or of your own?

Comment: Well I got information to allow me to use my ftp server, but I'll mark this as my answer since I actually used it (the site I made here looked nicer than the one I had on google sites...)

Answer (score 1):

[000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/) is actually a pretty reliable host, with decent and free advertisement-free hosting. It also supports typical web server things such as FTP access, cpanel and e-mail accounts.

Their limit on free hosting is basically low disk space (1.5 GB) and bandwidth (100 GB/mo) and some minor content restriction. If that seems fine for you, then I highly recommend it. Even on free accounts, their ticket response time is blazing.

Comment: So I created an account, but I can't find out how to set publish and update locations to a place here.

Comment: You should be able to just put [the site directory that's hosting it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), I think.

Comment: Ok correction, not HOW do I set the update location, WHERE is the update location? I can't find what URL to use...

Answer (score 0):

[NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/), while not free, lets you host your application on a pay as you go plan. There are [free web-hosts](http://www.110mb.com/), but most lack the features of costies, such as FTP access.

Comment: I don't see file hosting on site or fileshare as one of the services they provide on their website. Are you sure they provide this service? (I need to make this work for the update feature is really all).

Comment: It's a web host. If you have FTP access, type in the address of the FTP server. If not, publish it somewhere on your hard disk and copy it across.

Comment: I see we have a mis understanding here. I can't use FTP because Click-Once does not allow updates from an FTP location....